# NodeJS + Express JS with Gz file

Tags: node.js, express, unity-webgl

I'm trying to create a server to serve my Unity3d WebGL game.

My problem come from those request from the webgl game.

```
            dataUrl: "Release/build.data",
            codeUrl: "Release/build.js",
            asmUrl: "Release/build.asm.js",
            memUrl: "Release/build.mem",
```

My NodeJS server need to return those file but they are as buid.datagz, buidl.jsgz, etc

so i did :

```
app.use('/Release/build.asm.js', function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    res.contentType('application/x-javascript');
    res.sendFile(clientFolder + '/Release/build.asm.jsgz');
});
```

it work as the server return the file but it's still gzipped,

so how do i tell NodeJS / Express to unzip the file before sending them?

Comment: You should use `compression` module at server side and let the server do compression on the basis of client capabilities rather than manually compressing it and decompressing it.

Comment: i already use app.use(compression());

Comment: then, probably you shouldn't manually compress the file.

Comment: also, set header `Content-Encoding: gzip`  for letting the client know about  content encoding

Comment: thx a lot, that was the missing part ;)